Set the rate of change of power for a PSU using only current limit
I have a PSU that has no power controls, I can only set the current limit and the voltage limit, and I need to control a resistive load such that the rate of change of the power is limited to a set value. I'm using labview for the controls the PSU is the BK precision MR160120 and the load is a set of resistive heaters the power rate of change limit is given by our customer. The heater is around 7ohms but does vary with temperature.
I thought this would be easy ohms law problem but has not yet found an easy answer.
For all the tests below I have the voltage of the supply set much higher than the the IR value based on the current limit, so the voltage is just being driven by the resistance of the load.
So I first tried taking the ramp rate which the customer gave in W/Hr at 600W/Hr or 0.16W/s I took a measurement of the current and the voltage and divided the ramp rate by the voltage so in theory getting:
(W/s)/V = I/s
So theoretically that is the most I could increase the current by to stay under the specified ramp rate.
That however did not work it was above (from a quick look ~2x above which stuck in my mind through the rest of this) the set ramp rate.
I thought this issue was coming because as the current changes so does the voltage, so you increase the current by and amount that was assuming the voltage would stay constant but when the voltage rises it ends up above what we want.
So I tried a similar thing using the rework of power to P=(I^2)R thinking this could get around the issue of the voltage changing with the current. I got R from dividing the measured voltage by the measured current then took my ramp rate and divided that by the calculated R and took the square root.
deltaI = sqrt(deltaP/resistance)
This was actually worse than my original method and actually increased as the voltage and current increased leading to an accelerating ramp rate.
Thinking maybe I was getting messed up with the sqrt leading the the square root of seconds (I think that should not matter but even more so my time step was 1 second so it should not have mattered) I instead changed to dividing the ramp rate by the calculated resistance and the measured power, but that just got me back to my original equation.
I took a sleep and in the morning thought I should look at it as derivatives. So the derivative of the P=(I^2)R in respect to P,I and time should (I believe) be
dP/dt = 2(dI/dt)R
This assumes over the 1second time span the temperature based resistance change of the load is negligible so treat it as a constant.
So set dP/dT to be the w/s change of the ramp rate and solve for dI/dt, partly because it appeared that taking the derivative of the square would give me the factor of 2 that appeared to be missing in the first test.
dI/dt = (dP/dt)/2R
But again this rate was off from the start and accelerated with increasing power/current/voltage.
I went through several more iterations talking through it with 2 other engineers some that were tried none of which worked.
Eventually I wanted to circle back to where I started just dividing the ramp rate by the measured voltage which as first glance looked to be around 2x the desired ramp rate. Letting it run longer it maintained over a truncated test 2x what the desired rate was. Setting the I rate of change to be half that value got it to be nearly dead on, it might be oscillating, or it might be noise but it basically sits right around that desired value without large excursions and averaging the actual ramp rate it converges on the set value.
So I wanted to ask y'all (I'm technically a mech E but taught myself enough EE stuff to be the EE for my company) what am I doing wrong, why do I need that factor of 2 to make this work, the math does not seem to work out. One of the other engineers brought up I'm not exactly doing a derivative when looking at 1s time scales so maybe that is why those formulas did not work? Perhaps since I only have the voltage value before the change and I want the average change to be my ramp rate I am really taking the average of 2 points so that could introduce a factor of 2?
I have something that works, I am just trying to understand why does it work. and how to better approach a problem like this. It seemed so simple when I started.
Thanks for any help, sorry its been a long day looking at these formulas please let me know what I can better clarify to help you help me.

As you observed (assuming constant resistance), power is proportional to voltage squared or current squared. So if you want to ramp power linearly, the voltage (or current) must follow a square-root curve.
But if your resistance can vary, then you can't do this as a simple open-loop control at all. You need to write a LabView program that measures the voltage and current going to the load, computes the power from that, compares that to the power you actually want at that particular moment, and incrementally adjusts the voltage set point up or down as needed.

To your second paragraph that is exactly what I have except it is adjusting the current setpoint. but the question is on how to best pick the next setpoint to not exceed the rate. And why does (W/s)/(V/2) satisfy the best next setpoint.

The setpoint for power (W) is simply the given parameter (W/s) multiplied by the elapsed time in seconds (s).
